# Is it possible to pack two different modules in one webpack.config?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a JS code which holds two modules under `src` folder.

- awsdk: main business logic with main models and services
- awfre: like a sub module, uses the first with some new business logic.

We want `webpack` to have two JS files, one per each folder (as explained above), is it possible?

NOTE: i'm using webpack v.^3.10.0

**EDIT:**
This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const pkg = require('./package.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const banner = `${pkg.name} - ${pkg.version} - (c) 2017 - ${pkg.author} - ${pkg.homepage} \n\n ${fs.readFileSync('LICENSE').toString()}`;

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './awsdk_module/lib/'),
    filename: 'awsdk.js',
    library: 'awsdk',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    noParse: [/dtrace-provider$/, /safe-json-stringify$/, /mv/],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, './src/awsdk'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, './specs'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    console: false,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    module: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './specs'),
    inline: true,
    port: 8081,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(banner),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Use two entry files?

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth yes, each folder has it's own entry

Comment: You can use splitChunks to pull each of them into their own file but that doesn't guarantee independence. If you want complete independence for the two bundles you can run webpack in multi-compiler mode where you build the two modules independently but at the same time. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler

Answer (score 2):

Webpack supports multiple outputs via the `entry` configuration field.

Just give it an object. Something like this:

```
{
  entry: {
    awsdk: require.resolve(__dirname, './awsdk/index.js'),
    awfre: require.resolve(__dirname, './awfre/index.js')
  }
}
```

You will also need to update `output.filename` to use the `[name]` placeholder:

```
output: {
  filename: "[name].js"
}
```

Note that by default webpack v4 will try and pull out shared dependencies into "vendor" bundles so you may end up with more output bundles than you give it entries.

Comment: I ran your code and I got: `ERROR in chunk awfre [entry]
awsdk.js
Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename awsdk.js`, Do I need to modify some more fields in the file ?

Comment: Please share your config. Probably you are setting output to a fixed filename and not using a placeholder. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42148632/2039244

Comment: I updated my question with my original config file. please advice if you can.

Comment: @roeygol I have updated my answer with an extra step (use `[name]` placeholder) that should fix your issue.