# Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

My webpack config gives the following error `Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html`

when I delete the htmlWebpackPlugin it works, but I won't get any html to show. I'm using Vue.js and my config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  mode: argv && argv.mode || 'development',
  devtool: (argv && argv.mode || 'development') === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'eval',

  entry: './src/app.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  node: false,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.vue',
      '.json'
    ],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['dist']
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        toType: 'dir'
      }]
    })
  ],

  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    https: true,
    open: true,
    overlay: true,
    port: 9000
  }
});
```

My file structure looks like this

[image]

I've looked at [Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148632/conflict-multiple-assets-emit-to-the-same-filename) but no solution worked for me, are there any other options?

Comment: I am getting the same error due to the CopyWebpackPlugin.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that [Vue loader also emits](https://dev.to/lavikara/setup-vue-webpack-and-babel-boo#p-7) `index.html`?

Try:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
  filename: 'anotherFileName.html',
}),
```

Comment: To be honest, I've given up on this project