# Webpack, optimization chunking gives "Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

**Info**

I am trying to generate my own webpack config and have some problems getting it working.

**Problem**

When trying to use optimization to split files into chunks I get the a error like underneath

> Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename static/js/bundle.js (chunks main and vendors-node_modules_react-hot-loader_patch_js-node_modules_react_jsx-dev-runtime_js-node_mod-4610d2)

If I remove the optimization section it works but without chunking. I have looked to the create react app [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L309) to get something to reference while generating this.

As you can see they have the optimization section working with chunking in both development and production. Why do I get the conflict error when using it?

**Code**

Minified/simplified version of my config (runtimeChunk disabled, as it also gives the same conflict error)

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
    process.env.BABEL_ENV = "development";

    return {
        mode: "development",
        entry: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src"],
        output: {
            path: undefined,
            publicPath: "/",
            filename: "static/js/bundle.js",
            chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: false,
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: "all",
                name: false
            },
            // runtimeChunk: {
            //     name: (entrypoint) => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`,
            // },
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: [path.join(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"],
            alias: {
                "react-dom": "@hot-loader/react-dom",
            },
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ["babel-loader"],
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"),
            }),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        ],
        devServer: {
            compress: true,
            hot: true,
            contentBase: "./build",
            historyApiFallback: true,
        },
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
    };
};
```

.babelrc

```json
{"presets": [["react-app", {"runtime": "automatic"}]]}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it to work had to change `filename: "static/js/bundle.js"` to `filename: "static/js/[name].js"`

```js
output: {
    path: undefined,
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "static/js/[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an ejected [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) and you get a similar  error

> Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename static/js/bundle.js
> (chunks main and runtime-main)

you can just change the filename property in the output configuration from

```js
filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
```

to

```js
filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].js',
```

Where the `[name]` placeholder is giving a different name to each output bundle instead of a fixed one.

In my case it was caused by the `runtime-main.js` file which I was generating with the `runtimeChunk` property inside `optimization`.

```js
runtimeChunk: {
  name: entrypoint => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`,
},
```